# Windows Mobile Device with Webcams Plugged In

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, webcam

I am exploring the possibility of plugging webcams (preferrably any webcam so I don't get tied to a particular hardware vendor) into a Windows Mobile 5 or 6 device, and write a piece of software app that allows user to click a button in that software app to get the webcam to take pictures or video streams.

So, I will need to know if this is possible to write a software app to do so on Windows Mobile 5 or 6 platforms? .NET is preferred but not essential.

What exactly do the webcam need to adhere to (for example, TWAIN)?

I had a look on the internet but no luck so far.

Any pointers will be welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will be difficult if not impossible to do. The main reason is that most Web Cameras are USB devices and I know of none Windows Mobile devices that can act as USB hosts.

Perhaps you could do it with Bluetooth Cameras. In that case, the manufacturer must supply a driver/SDK that can run in Windows Mobile.